Is it possible to visually understand why the weighted sum of all frequencies' complex exponentials equal in amplitude is dirac delta?
The Fourier Transform of the dirac delta function is 1 for all values of w. A way to think about any function in the time domain is the addition of complex exponentials at different frequencies added on top of each other. The classic square function being represented by different frequencies as an example. It's easy to conceptualize that a periodic wave that is the addition of maybe cosines at 2 or 3 different fundamemtal frequencies will have a value in the frequency domain at those frequencies and 0 everywhere else. However, I'm having trouble convincing myself that if you take infinite complex exponentials in the time domain at every frequency with a weight of 1 (and, if I'm understanding integrals correctly also weighed by how many samples there are in a length of 1 AKA dt/integration), that the equivalent would be infinity at 0 and 0 everywhere else (the dirac delta). Could it be that, because delta is discontinuous, the Fourier Transform being 1 isn't really true? Or maybe it's continuous at a certain shape just infinitely narrow (continuity is not part of its definition one way or another) and that it makes sense because of an addition of real and imaginary and positive and negative waves? Just trying to understand what that looks like.

See the answer I gave on this post https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/94096/rigorous-derivation-of-autocorrelation-of-white-noise/94102#94102 . If you want a visual aid, form a DFT matrix. If you sum along each column you get a delta, if you sum along each row you get a delta. Weighting the amplitudes of each column (or row) equally with a real valued number won’t change this outcome.

Perhaps this answer might help, though it uses Hertzian frequencies $f$ instead of radian frequencies $\omega$.

Do you have the same challenge understanding why a DC value in the time domain is an impulse in frequency at f=0 (and are you comfortable with the reciprocity properties of the Fourier Transform to allow us to temporarily swap time and frequency)? If you can find an intuitive explanation going from time to frequency, then you can find the same intuition for going from frequency to time if you relate either to the exponentials involved.
